# JavaScript .then method

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want `consloe.log("Hello")` print after I click a Button in this code.

```js
async function remove_tag() {
  let pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    function done() {
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      function button() {
        let tag = document.getElementById("main_1");
        tag.remove();
      }
      btn.addEventListener("click", button)
      let msg = "done";
      return msg;
    }
    resolve(done());
  })
  let wait_promise = await pr;
  return wait_promise;
}

remove_tag()
  .then((value) => {
    console.log("hello")
  });
```

I try a lot of time but "Hello" is print before I click the button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dv72.png)

Comment: You are not calling resolve on the click..... The resolve line should be in the poorly named function `button` And the `done` method does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're calling `resolve` immediately in your `Promise` definition, causing the `Promise` to resolve immediately. You need to call it inside your `button` function so that it's run when it's clicked.

```js
async function remove_tag(){
    let pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        function button(){
            let tag = document.getElementById("main_1");
            tag.remove();
            let msg = "done";
            resolve(msg);
        }
        btn.addEventListener("click", button);
    })
    let wait_promise = await pr;
    return wait_promise;
}

remove_tag()
.then((value)=>{
    console.log("hello");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function remove_tag() {
  let pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    function done() {
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      function button() {
        let tag = document.getElementById("main_1");
        tag.remove();
        console.log("hello"); // move console.log here
      }
      btn.addEventListener("click", button);
      let msg = "done";
      return msg;
    }
    resolve(done());
  });
  let wait_promise = await pr;
  return wait_promise;
}

remove_tag();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
async function remove_tag() {
  let pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    function done() {
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      function button() {
        let tag = document.getElementById("main_1");
        tag.remove();
        resolve(); // resolve the promise after button click
      }
      btn.addEventListener("click", button);
    }
    done();
  })
  await pr; // wait for the promise to be resolved after button click
}

remove_tag()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("hello");
  });
```